# How to properly configure Ext.chart.CartesianChart so that the graph is not trimmed from above?

Tags: extjs

How to make the numbers above the graphs not cut off from above?
Sandbox https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sqj
It shows that August and December are cut off from above.

Comment: do you have label problem or what ???I always post an image so people can understand me fully

Comment: your fiddle isn't working

Comment: It's working you only have to click on the chart package on the left, not sure why it's not saved in the fiddle.

Comment: I apologize, forgot to put the checkbox. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try innerPadding, here's a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ssc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting issue, don't know how to solve it. I have only written a "workaround" to display the left numeric axis and set the maximum so it's bigger than the max value in the chart.

```
axes: [{
    type: 'category',
    position: 'bottom'
},{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: 'pay'
    // maximum: 12000 // set dynamically
}],

...

listeners: {
    beforerender: function (me){
        // I guess it could be much fencier than this
        var store = me.getStore();
        var l = store.getData().items.length;
        var max = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < l ; i++){
            if(store.getAt(i).get('pay') > max){
                max = store.getAt(i).get('pay');
            }
        }
        max = Math.ceil((max+max*0.1)/1000)*1000;
        me.getAxes()[1].setMaximum(max)
    }
},
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sqs

[image]

Comment: @SalmanhassanOkZ this is his problem http://imgur.com/a/KvPfV the bar "tooltips" are cut from above

Comment: @pagep Yes! Cut from above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
label: {
        field: 'pay',
        display: 'inside',
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        renderer: 'onSeriesLabelRender'
    }
```

[I updated your fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sr7)
you can make label disply: 'inside', and also you can make orientation: 'vertical', of your label

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Good solution!

Comment: if you get your answer please tick mark it so people will not have to answer it..thanks